# Blurry signs in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card

When I look around, the signs are blurry. can anyone help? I have a Intel core 2 extreme cpu, 6gb of ram, and GeForce GTX 550TI gpu.

When I record using software, the signs are perfect ([fraps recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-nD7Us3ty_ybFF2MVBkVTNGZ2M/view?usp=sharing)) But here is my phone recording of what it looks like in real life: [Phone recording](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-nD7Us3ty_yMUdVeWxsbVhvWXc).

Comment: Just the signs? Is that so bad...?

Comment: @TimmyJim what if he is making an adventure map?

Comment: A screenshot of the problem and the video options would be appreciated

Comment: when I record the video the signs are perfectly fine, and I have no idea if my monitor has gsync but its model is: ViewSonic VA2055Sm.

Comment: So it looks like they are only blurry when you are moving your head?

Comment: Evan, we would prefer if you answered your own question with what you did to fix your problem. That way, you can help future visitors who have the same problem.

Comment: I agree with @Schism. It's great your problem is solved, but answering the question can help others with your problem in the future

Comment: Cool, glad you fixed it! Can you tell us what was wrong with your monitor, and how you fixed it? That way the next person with the same problem will be helped by you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my monitor's response time was 25 ms, which sucked for gaming. I need to buy a new monitor with at most 7ms.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yea and because it's accepted it'll be easier for people to find, too.